# "Unfortunately Gallery has stopped" in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, gallery, genymotion

I use Genymotion to develop apps with Google Nexus 6 - 6.0.0 - API23 - 1440x2560.

When I click Gallery, I got "Unfortunately Gallery has stopped".

Any ideas?